# Conexión a SQLITE desde Java es Null

Tags: java, sqlite

estoy haciendo un aplicativo pequeño, por lo que decidí usar Sqlite para tener una base de datos portable, sin embargo, al hacer la conexión a la base de datos, el valor de la conexión siempre es nula. Tengo el archivo .jar de sqlite en las librerías (trabajo desde java), ya hice todas las importaciones, pero sigue sin funcionar, a continuación pongo el código:

```
static Connection cn=null;
public static Connection Enlace(Connection cn)throws SQLException{
    String ruta="C:\\Users\\Aleja Blanco\\Desktop\\Randomizer\\database.db";
    try{
      DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.sqlite.JDBC());
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

      cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+ruta);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    return cn;

}
```

Y éstas son las importaciónes:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

Tengo el sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1.jar en las librerías:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando, o si es un error mío, les agradecería.

Comment: Me pregunto, ¿por qué el método `Enlace` tiene un parámetro de tipo `Connection`? Se supone que el método retorna un objeto de tipo `Connection`. Por lo tanto, es innecesario. Además si el atributo `cn` siempre queda con `null` es porque el nombre del parámetro coincide con el atributo.

Comment: El método requiere que especifíque su tipo, de igual forma la variable, necesita un identificador, así la haya declarado con anterioridad, si no lo hago me da error

Comment: Simplemente quita esta línea: `static Connection cn=null;`. Con el método ya se tiene acceso al objeto `Connection`.

Comment: Y también elimina el parámetro y simplemente agrega una variable local de tipo `Connection`.